# Rational CC CQ upgrade

Tags: clearcase

We are planning to upgrade CC/CQ version 7.1.2.13 to 8.0.x.x as the earlier version has gone out of support. As we do not have a test machine where we can try out these things and also there is no dedicated team to do this, we are all novice in this regard. Can someone please help me with the following:

Server: Windows 2008 server enterprise edition.

We use installation manager 1.6.3 for installation or upgradation.

Is it required that we uninstall 7.1.2.13 using installation manager and then install 8.0.x.x. or does the installation manager do it automatically.

Also, there is an 'upgrade' option in installation manager, should we use it to upgrade, instead of uninstalling earlier version and then installing the latest version?

If un-installation is required, then could you please let me know the steps to restore the VOBs for CC and shcemas, schema repository,user database for ClearQuest. Basically how can we make things work like before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it required that we uninstall 7.1.2.13 using installation manager and then install 8.0.x.x.

I find it easier to uninstall/install than upgrading.
Simply make sure to backup your registry and stirage (vob and views)

And you can start upgrading to the latest IM you can find ([currently 1.8](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037640#DNLD))

Most of the steps are described in:

- "[Planning your upgrade of Rational ClearCase](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_planning_upgrade.htm)"
- "[Planning your upgrade (ClearQuest)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearquest.install_upgrade.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_upgrade.htm)"

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple Rational products on the same machine, e.g. CC and CQ 7.X, I think the upgrade path wont work at all because IBM IM will complain that another incompatible version is on the system if you tried. Extremely stupid but I've learnt to accept this for all the Rational products.

So complete uninstall and reinstallation of all products is the way to go.